# Process socket data with a leading length value

Tags: php, sockets, php-5.3, php-socket

This is a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742449/sending-sockets-data-with-a-leading-length-value) about how to process prefixed messages received from a network socket. What I try to do is:

1. Read the first 4 bytes (which is the $prefix and represents the length of the message)
2. Check if $prefix has really the size of 4 bytes and if it's an integer
3. Read the complete $message using the length from $prefix
4. Check if message has really the size of $prefix bytes

So far I've the following two lines of code:

```
    $prefix = socket_read($socket, 4, PHP_BINARY_READ); //No 1.
    //No 2: how to do the checks?
    $message = socket_read($socket, $prefix, PHP_BINARY_READ); //No 3.
    //No 4: how to do the checks?
```

How can I do the mentioned checks?

A little side note: all data sent through the network socket connection is in UTF8, little-endian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can validate the length of the binary string you have received by simply using [`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen):

```
$prefix = socket_read($socket, 4, PHP_BINARY_READ);
if (strlen($prefix) != 4) {
    // not 4 bytes long
}
```

According to your previous question, this binary string represents a 32-bit long. [Unpack](http://php.net/unpack) it as such (with the same format specifier you use when *pack-ing* it), then fetch the message and use `strlen` again to validate the length:

```
$length = current(unpack('l', $prefix));
$message = socket_read($socket, $length, PHP_BINARY_READ);
if (strlen($message) != $length) {
    // $message not the size of $length
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help, really appreciate it. To check if the $prefix is an integer, I have to check the unpacked value in $length (is_int($length)), is that correct?

Comment: @Mike: `unpack` will return `false` if `$prefix` is not of the format specified (a 32-bit signed long, `l`, in the above example). If unpack returns anything but `false`, you don't have to check for `is_int`.